# Create file DSN for an Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database

I want to connect an Access form with an Azure SQL Server Database. In order to do that I have to create new `File DSN` (because I want this data source to be used on all the machines and not only mine).

When I try to do this from the Administrative tools, I cannot even connect to SQL Server on Azure using my SQL credentials. I get this error :

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '28000'
SQL Server Error: 18456
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user xxxx
```

The credentials are correct because:

1. I am able to connect to the database using SSMS with the same credentials
2. I get no errors when I try to do the same thing with `User` or `System` DSN. But I don't want this because I want to share the data source with all the machines.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you paste total error

Comment: That's all of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in my test:

Say if you have Azure database with server name **DBSERVER**.database.windows.net, in order to setup your file DSN, you would have to specify the login with the format below:

```
LOGIN@DBSERVER
```

That should workaround the issue.

Regards,
Lin

**EDIT:**

I’m reproducing this with [contained user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929188.aspx). Anyways the workaround is to manually create a txt file with the content below and change the file extension to .dsn.

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0
UID=USERNAME@DBSERVER
Encrypt=yes
DATABASE=DBNAME
WSID=HOSTNAME
APP=Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
SERVER=tcp:DBSERVER.database.windows.net,1433
```

Comment: Even with this, I get the same error. As I said this happens only when I try File DSN, it works just fine when I try other DSN (User or system)

Comment: Yes, somehow the file DSN wizard only works when the corresponding login is mapped to master database even with default database specified.

Answer (score 0):

Usually SQL Server Native creates problems in file DSN. I hope below-mentioned query will work as it is working fine for me

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
UID=nazim.virani
DATABASE=DBNAME
WSID=HOSTNAME
APP=Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
SERVER=INSTANCE
```